# How can I test implementations of SOCKS5 proxy 'BIND' and 'UDP ASSOCIATE' commands?

Tags: java, sockets, proxy, client-server, socks

Using RFC 1928, I have implemented SOCKS5 'BIND' and 'UDP ASSOCIATE' commands on Java, but I haven't found any way to test their work. I have tried browser (Firefox), FTP server and client in active and passive mods (run server on my Android phone and connected to it using Filezilla client for Linux), e-mail client (Thunderbird and SMTP). But every app always sends a request on connection (using only 'CONNECT' command) and nothing else (but all of them work normal). So, how I can test commands?

Comment: So sad, no answer. I want it too, are you found it?